# asp.net error giving me row count zero

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, enterprise-library

hi i am using microsoft enterprise library below is the code

for dataset

```
Public Function FetchUserValue(ByVal uemail As String) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Try
        Dim query As String = String.Format("select * from v_userdetails where uemail='{0}' ", uemail)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return ds
End Function
```

the code behind function

```
Dim obj As New barter
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim user As String = CookieUtil.GetEncryptedCookieValue("MERE1000CR").ToString
Try
    Dim dtProducts As DataTable = obj.FetchUserValue(user).Tables(0)
    Dim rp As System.Data.DataRow
    If dtProducts.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To dtProducts.Rows.Count - 1
        rp = dtProducts.Rows(rowIndex)
        Try
        If Convert.ToInt32(rp(0)) = 1 Then
            sb.Append(" <div>Welcome " & Convert.ToInt32(rp(2)).ToString & "</div>" & _
                  "<div class='dps'><img src='" & Convert.ToInt32(rp(9)).ToString & "' width='100px'/></div><div class='inf'></div></div style='clear:both'></div>")

        ElseIf Convert.ToInt32(rp(0)) = 0 Then
            Response.Redirect("Activation.aspx")
        ElseIf Convert.ToInt32(rp(0)) = 2 Then
            Response.Redirect("Blocked.aspx")
        End If

        Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
    profiler.InnerHtml = sb.ToString
    Else
    MsgBox("something wrong...")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

i am getting row count 0 even when there are rows when i run same query in sql.... any suggesion??

Comment: Shouldn't your obj be declared as `Dim obj As New barter()`?

Comment: no barter is different class file even if i put barter() ,it doesnt make any difference...

Comment: Hmm, Have you checked that the value of the user variable that you retrieve from the cookie exists in the table in the database.

Comment: yes  it does even if i change query and insert the value rather than pasing through variable it still gives me 0 row count

Comment: error is solved i just removed dataset.xsd file from project .